# Mostrar hora/data (atual ou futura) a partir do select com JS

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Olá. Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso? A ideia é mostrar a hora programada obtida a partir do select (agendamento) - quando já estiver selecionado ou ser selecionado o "agora" não precisa aparecer nada. Então quando selecionar 3 horas, 6 horas... deve pegar a hora atual, e somar a mais 3 ou 6, para saber a hora que será publicada.

Ocorre que select.value apesar de obter o valor certo, quando inserido no dataAgendada não mostra a hora certa, mostra uma hora bem frente, de dias ou meses futuros. Gostaria também, que fosse mostrado a hora nessa formatação DD/MM/AAAA - HH:MM:SS.

```
<select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="agendamento" id="agendamento" tabindex="14">
<option value="3">3 horas</option>
<option value="6">6 horas</option>
<option value="9">9 horas</option>
<option value="12">12 horas</option>
<option value="agora">Agora</option>
</select>
<!-- o "agora" quando inserido na primeira posição (que será a certa) impede totalmente o funcionamento. -->

<strong id="agendamento_data" class="col-md-12 text-end small"></strong>

<script>
var select = document.getElementById('agendamento');
const mostraData = document.getElementById('agendamento_data');
var dataAgora = new Date();
var dataAgendada = new Date();

dataAgendada.setHours(dataAgora.getHours() + select.value);
mostraData.innerHTML = dataAgendada;
// Queria que exibiesse a data nesse formato DD/MM/AAAA - HH:MM:SS

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
    dataAgendada.setHours(dataAgora.getHours() + select.value);
    mostraData.innerHTML = dataAgendada;
    // Queria que exibiesse a data nesse formato DD/MM/AAAA - HH:MM:SS
})
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**O problema:** `dataAgora.getHours` retorna um número (integer), e `select.value` retorna uma string. Em JavaScript, quando você usa o operador `+` entre número e string (mesmo que a string seja um número), ele vai **concatenar** os valores como strings, e não o que você quer, que é **somar** dois números.

**Explicando seu código:** Se você rodar seu script às 22 horas, com a opção 6 no select, o `getHours` retornará 22, que será concatenado com a string `6`. Por isso, o `setHours` adicionará 226 horas (e não 28), resultando numa data 9 dias além do que você pretenderia.

**Solução:** Converta o tipo do retorno de `select.value` para número antes de somar. Assim, a operação será realizada entre dois números, e o valor das horas será somado, que é o que você quer: `dataAgendada.setHours(dataAgora.getHours() + Number(select.value));`

Além disso, lembre de testar para não fazer nada caso a opção selecionada não seja um número. Código final:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('agendamento');
const mostraData = document.getElementById('agendamento_data');

function mostrarDataAgendada() {
  const dataAgora = new Date();
  const dataAgendada = new Date();
  const horasPorSomar = Number(select.value)

  if (typeof(horasPorSomar) == "boolean" || 
  isNaN(horasPorSomar)) return
  dataAgendada.setHours(dataAgora.getHours() + horasPorSomar);
  mostraData.textContent = dataAgendada.toLocaleString();
}

mostrarDataAgendada()
select.addEventListener('change', mostrarDataAgendada)
```

A referência dessas funções pode ser encontrada aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: obrigado! adicionei `Number(select.value)` como orientou e deu certo! Apenas a formatação da data/hora, e o caso do texto ainda estou precisando resolver, mas o principal e mais importante já está resolvido, obrigado!

Comment: A formatação não funcionou com o `toLocaleString`? Eu não comentei, mas inseri na resposta.

Comment: Deu certo! Recebi vi agora a atualização, está funcionando perfeitamente, ja com a hora formatada. Somente a opção de texto "agora" que exibe ainda!

Comment: Eu não entendi o problema do "agora", mas talvez resolva você alterar a option do Select, mantendo o texto interno como "agora" e alterando o `value` para 0 (ele vai somar 0 horas).

Comment: hehe foi que fiz, coloquei o zero lá hehe! O "agora" na verdade era desnecessário aparecer a hora, pelo fato da publicação ser imediata (a mesma hora do relógio rs), então sem agendamento. Mas o principal já está mais que resolvido, e você ainda melhorou o código. Obrigado novamente, abraço!